# Performance of listing S3 bucket with prefix and delimiter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

According to the [listing documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html) it is possible to treat a large navigate number of keys as though they were hierarchial. I am planning to store a large number of keys (let's say a few hundred million), distributed over a sensible-sized 'hierarchy'.

What is the performance of using a prefix and delimiter? Does it require a full enumeration of keys at the S3 end, and therefore be an O(n) operation? I have no idea whether keys are stored in a big hash table, or whether they have indexing data structures, or if they're stored in a tree or what.

I want to avoid the situation where I have a very large number of keys and navigating the 'hierarchy' suddenly becomes difficult.

So if I have the following keys:

- `abc/def/ghi/0`
- `abc/def/ghi/1`
- `abc/def/ghi/...`
- `abc/def/ghi/100,000,000,000`

Will it affect the speed of the query `Delimiter='/, Prefix='abc/def'`?

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the [Request Rate and Performance Considerations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html) document that Sandeep referenced (which is not applicable to your use case), AWS hasn't publicized very much regarding S3 performance. It's probably private intellectual property. So I doubt you'll find very much information unless you can get it somehow from AWS directly.

However, some things to keep in mind:

1. Amazon S3 is built for massive scale. Millions of companies are using S3 with millions of keys in millions of buckets.
2. AWS promotes the prefix + delimiter as a very valid use case.
3. There are common data structures and algorithms used in computer science that AWS is probably using behind the scenes to efficiently retrieve keys. One such data structure is called a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or Prefix Tree.

Based on all of the above, chances are that it's much better than an order O(n) algorithm when you retrieve listing of keys. I think you are safe to use prefixes and delimiters for your hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, that was my intuition too. I was looking for some confirmation. The thing that made me think twice was that the prefix and delimiter are arbitrary, meaning that a simple trie wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Tries work beautifully with arbitrary prefixes, that is what they are made for. Once you follow the nodes down the tree (which will be O(n) on the length of your prefix), only sub-nodes are candidates for retrieval. You never look outside your prefix. When retrieving sub-nodes, you stop traversing the trie when you hit your delimiter node, thus quickly eliminating those keys.

Comment: I tested this just now, using the List Objects V1 API on a bucket with ~10 million objects, where the objects are stored as "image/a/b/c/abcdef..." with a/b/c being the first 3 hex digits of a sha of the file... so there are 16 prefixes, `image/0/` through `image/f/` and the objects are reasonably evenly distributed throughout the keyspace, with two more "levels" of delimiters.  Requesting a bucket listing with `delimiter=/&prefix=image/` returns the listing of all 16 expected `<CommonPrefixes>` in 225ms with a single hit to the API, clearly better than O(n).  How they do it isn't known. +1

Comment: O(n) _in the prefix length_, not the number of leaves: in your case, the prefix is `image/`. Then it could just do a DFS search from that node stopping at every delimiter to enumerate `0`-`f`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are not using a continuous sequence (such as date 2016-13-08, 2016-13-09 and so on) in the prefix you shouldn't face any problem. If your keys are auto-generated as a continuous sequence then prepend a randomly generated hash key to the keys (aidk-2016-13-08, ujlk-2016-13-09).
The amazon documentation says:

> Amazon S3 maintains an index of object key names in each AWS region. Object keys are stored in UTF-8 binary ordering across multiple partitions in the index. The key name dictates which partition the key is stored in. Using a sequential prefix, such as timestamp or an alphabetical sequence, increases the likelihood that Amazon S3 will target a specific partition for a large number of your keys, overwhelming the I/O capacity of the partition. If you introduce some randomness in your key name prefixes, the key names, and therefore the I/O load, will be distributed across more than one partition.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

Comment: Thanks. I read that but it didn't seem relevant to the big-O complexity of iteration at a given point in the key 'hierarchy'.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon indicates that prefix naming strategies, such as randomized hashing, no longer influence S3 lookup performance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html